# Execute return as function caller

Tags: php, function, scope, return

Is there a way to execute a `return` statement as a function's caller?
Take:

index.php:

```php
require action.php
```

action.php:

```php
require check.php
checkAccess() || return;
doSomeSecretStuff();
```

check.php:

```php
function checkAccess() {
    if(loggedIn)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

and I was wondering if there is a way to execute that `return` statement forcing action.php to stop from inside `checkAccess()`?

kinda like `get_function_caller().eval("return");`

(super-pseudo code)

Comment: Sorry still not sure what your trying to achieve.

Comment: quitting action.php, though only executing checkAccess();

Comment: No, it's not possible. Look into using exceptions instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this:

```
check();
foo();
```

There is *no way* that `check` could `return` for you, so it's *guaranteed* that `foo` will be executed. And that's a good thing, otherwise you'd have no guarantees about your execution flow in your code.

The only way this may skip the execution of `foo` is if a fatal error occurred in `check` and everything halts, or—and here it comes—if `check` *throws an exception*.

You'd use this something like this:

```js
let foo = false;

function assertFoo() {
  if (!foo) {
    throw new Error('Not enough foo');
  }
}

function bar() {
  assertFoo();
  console.log('Barrr!');
}

try {
  bar();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```